# Why are some Django methods PascalCase and others snake_case?

Tags: python, django, naming-conventions, pascalcasing, snakecasing

As far as I know, the convention is to use snake_case for method names, so why are some methods in Django PascalCase, e.g. Django's [TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#testcase) Class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Django's Testing framework inherits from Python's [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) module. That, in turn, is heavily based on the Java [JUnit](https://junit.org) framework. Java uses PascalCase naming conventions; when the code was ported to Python the names were kept.